# Undeclared identifier Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I can't seem to get round this error; use of undeclared identifier 'ageBy'.
I dont understand why am getting it as i have the import Person.h in my code.
Thanks for your time and any help.

Person.h

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
 int _age;
 int _years;
 NSString *_name;
 NSString *_job;

} 

-(void)setAge:(int)age;
-(int)age;

-(void)setName:(NSString *)name;
-(NSString *)name;

-(void)setJob:(NSString *)job;
-(NSString *)job;

-(NSString *)summaryString;

-(void)ageBy:(int)years;


@end
```

Person.m

```
#import "Person.h"
@implementation Person

-(void)setAge:(int)age{
  _age = age;
}
-(int)age{
  return _age;
}
-(void)setName:(NSString *)name{
  _name = name;
}
-(NSString *)name{
  return _name; }

-(void)setJob:(NSString *)job{
  _job = job;
}
-(NSString *)job{
  return _job;
}

-(NSString *)summaryString{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Person %@ is %d years old and is a  %@",_name,_age,_job];

-(void)ageBy:(int)years{
  _years = years;
  _age = years + _age;

 }

 } 
 @end
```

Comment: You could eliminate 80% if this code by declaring a few properties instead of the ivars and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ageBy:` is defined inside `summaryString`. You probably want to move the curly bracket just before `@end` so that it is above `-(void)ageBy:(int)years`. So:

```
-(NSString *)summaryString{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Person %@ is %d years old and is a  %@",_name,_age,_job];
 } 

-(void)ageBy:(int)years{
  _years = years;
  _age = years + _age;

 }
```

Also as a style note, if `summaryString` is merely for debugging then you'd possibly be better off declaring it as [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description). The latter is the standard form for getting an implementation-dependand string description of an Objective-C object, with the net effect that collection objects like `NSArray` know to call `description` on all their child objects in order to create the correct output.

Comment: @ukbaz Another advantage of renaming your `summaryString` method to `description` is that it makes it easy to log a `Person` object: `NSLog(@"Person: %@", somePersonObject);`. There is no need to call `description` or your `summaryString` method.

Answer (score 4):

As was stated, the problem is caused by the `ageBy:` method being embedded in the `summaryString` method.

I wanted to demonstrate how this class could be written using modern Objective-C:

```
// Person.h
@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int age;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *job;

- (void)ageBy:(int)years;

@end

// Person.m
@implementation Person

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Person %@ is %d years old and is a %@", self.name, self.age, self.job];
}

- (void)ageBy:(int)years {
    self.age = self.age + years;
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm going to be Mr. Pedantic so as to impart an extra fact about `@property`s for the benefit of the originating poster: while `copy` is a good choice with any objects that can be mutable, the technical equivalent of the original code posted would be `strong` as he's not currently copying the properties.

Comment: @Tommy I'm glad you pointed that out. I should have been clearer that my use of `copy` should be considered an improvement and not an exact replacement for the original semantics. Thanks.